# Leaking RTCPeerConnections. Even after page refresh

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peer-connection

I have a pretty simple RTCPeerConnection app running. Uses Firebase for signaling. The RTCPeerConnections get established, and then I take the stream, and do the following with it:

```
let streamURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
```

Then I take that `streamURL` and set the `video.src = streamURL`. That is how I get it to see the remote users' video. Then, when I am done with the connection (I want to end the conversation) I do the following:

```
peerConnection.getLocalStreams().forEach(stream=>{
    stream.getTracks().forEach(t=>{
        t.stop();
        stream.removeTrack(t);
    });
});
peerConnection.close();
```

This ends the connection, including turns off the green light for my local webcam. This tells me that things have ended for the most part.

Then I check [chrome://webrtc-internals](http://chrome://webrtc-internals) and the connection is still there. Even after I refresh, the connection is there. That seems odd. How can it still be there, even after a refresh? Please help. Am I not ending the RTCPeerConnection correctly? I thought this was the right way. I just can't figure out how the webrtc internals can still show it EVEN AFTER a page refresh. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40210033/2885826 Look at that answer. It helps on how to create the stream correctly

Comment: This is Chrome I take it. When you say page refresh, are you refreshing the chrome://webrtc-internals page, or your page?

Comment: @jib I am refreshing my page. Not the webrtc-internals page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it right. The only thing missing is:

```
peerConnection = null;
```

to let the peer connection itself be garbage collected.

As I've [mentioned elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40210033/2885826) I'd avoid createObjectURL and use `video.srcObject = stream` directly instead, but that has to do with releasing the camera should you forget to stop all tracks.

I wouldn't read too much into Chrome's webrtc-internals page, because looking at peer connections is useful for debugging, even after the fact. The important question is: Are there any JavaScript or wire observable signs of a connection being open?

#### Example

You can try [this https fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/0xh941s9/) in two different tabs or windows and see things failing remotely.

Make sure you can see both fiddles at once, and click the [Start!] button in one of them to connect. You should see video in both places. Now when you click the [Stop!] button, you should see the following output on the other end (it may take a few seconds for all three to appear):

```
disconnected
failed
closed
```

Because I check for the `"failed"` state and close the connection on it (though in production it's more common to use [data channels to communicate hangups](http://jsfiddle.net/cef91vdg/)).

#### Chrome

That said, I won't fully rule out a bug in Chrome, in that it may hang on to resources longer than it should, as I see the same thing you're describing (but note that e.g. "packets sent" drops to zero when I click "Stop!", which is the important part).

Contrast with Firefox, where, when I go to about:webrtc (its equivalent to chrome://webrtc-internals) and hit refresh and the [Clear History] button, my peer connections are gone from the list.

Comment: This is exactly what I was wondering. After doing everything I can, I figured that the webrtc-internals must be busted or something.

Comment: Also, will use the srcObject instead of what I was doing. Thank you for the suggestions. These are great!