# how ( stop,exit ) video in webrtc navigator user media JavaScript

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, openwebrtc

how i stop and exit in pure js, stream webcam in WEBRTC api js , i have in my code the following script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#abrirModal").click(function() {
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
        var constraints = {
            audio: false,
            video: true
        };
        var live = document.getElementById("live");

        function successCallback(stream) {
            window.stream = stream; // stream available to console
            if (window.URL) {
                live.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            } else {
                live.src = stream;
            }
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $("#myModal").modal("hide");
            }, 9000);
        }

        function errorCallback(error) {
            console.log("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error);
        }

     navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
    });
});
 </script>
```

how close and exit web cam in other file.js for example:

```
  function exitWebCam () {  
     document.getElementById("live")."close the web cam";
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You end a stream by closing all of its tracks:

`stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) { track.stop(); })`

Answer (score 6):

What Philipp says. Also clear all references to the stream so it can be freed. Here you have a bug:

```
live.src = stream;
```

is **wrong** (`src` takes a URL, not a stream). Luckily it never runs since `window.URL` exists in all browsers that do WebRTC. But `createObjectURL` causes the camera to stay on. Instead do this:

```
if (typeof live.srcObject == "object") {
    live.srcObject = stream;
} else {
    live.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
}
```

Or just `live.srcObject = stream` as `srcObject` is implemented in all the WebRTC browsers by now (Chrome 54+). It handles resources correctly, so when you later do `live.srcObject = null` the browser knows it can garbage collect the stream (and turn off the camera should you have missed calling `track.stop()` on any of the tracks).

`createObjectURL` is terrible and deprecated, and leaves resources allocated until page navigation unless you remember to `revokeObjectURL`. It's why your camera never stops on its own, in case you were wondering, so if you see this pattern in code, please help stamp it out.

#### Compare

Try these for comparison. Video disappears after 2 seconds, but keep an eye on your camera light and the in-browser recording indicator. First with `srcObject` ([https fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/abb8v8e2/1) for Chrome):

(Cam indicator and light should go out after ~10 seconds in Firefox; ~20 seconds in Chrome.)

```js
var wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
  .then(stream => video.srcObject = stream)
  .then(() => wait(2000))
  .then(() => video.srcObject = null)
  .catch(e => console.log(e.name + ": "+ e.message));
```

```html
<video id="video" width="160" height="120" autoplay></video>
```

Then with `createObjectURL` (without `revokeObjectURL`) ([https fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/abb8v8e2/0) for Chrome):

(Stays on forever in both browsers.)

```js
var wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
  .then(stream => video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream))
  .then(() => wait(2000))
  .then(() => video.srcObject = null)
  .catch(e => console.log(e.name + ": "+ e.message));
```

```html
<video id="video" width="160" height="120" autoplay></video>
```

`track.stop()` called explicitly will stop it, but only if you've stopped *all* tracks, which can be easier than it sounds in general given that tracks can be cloned now. So avoid `createObjectURL`.