# How to stop streaming and shut down the camera

Tags: webrtc

I am using stream.stop() which is working fine in firefox but giving error in chrome that 'stream.stop() is undefined'.

In firefox however it is working it is also showing a warning that use MediaStreamTrack.stop() instead.

Which while using not working on safari/chrome both

I have tried MeadiaStream.stop() as well.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203036/how-stop-exit-video-in-webrtc-navigator-user-media-javascript

Answer (score 2):

I have used

```
mediaStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
```

to stop audio tracks and

```
mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
```

to stop video tracks