# Bug firefox 58 webcam webRTC

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc

I have tried the following example of the web camera in firefox and chrome (https://jsfiddle.net/codepo8/agaRe/4/).

```
function(stream) {
  if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { 
    video.mozSrcObject = stream;
  } else {
    var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    video.src = vendorURL ? vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
  }
  video.play();
},
```

Today firefox has been updated to version 58 and the example has stopped working.

However, in chrome it is still working.

Could you help me?

Comment: `navigator.getUserMedia` is  deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia

Comment: Please put your code in the question, not a link

Comment: Firefox 58 removed mozSrcObject. set the video.srcObject to stream. Works in all current browsers.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40210033/918910) for other problems with this pattern (wrt `createObjectURL`).

Answer (score 1):

The non-standard `mozSrcObject` was [removed in Firefox 58](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/58#APIs_2) in favor of `srcObject`.

Also, other lines in this function are wrong. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40210033/918910). All you need these days are:

```
function(stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.play();
},
```

This works in all browsers that support WebRTC.